# Trying to add edges and nodes to graph using networkx

Tags: python, database, networkx

So I have a dataframe that i'm trying to put into a graph using networkx. A sample of the data frame is below:

```
Alabama Alabama 0
Alabama Alaska  0
Alabama Arizona 0
Alabama Arkansas    1
Alabama California  1
Alabama Colorado    1
Alabama Connecticut 0
Alabama Delaware    0
```

I'm trying to have it setup so that the 0s and 1s are edges between the corresponding nodes that are in the same column. So nodes Alabama Alabama would have a self loop of 0, ect. I tried

`graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([test3])`

But it's giving me the error: dtype: int64 must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.

How should I go about creating this graph considering I might need to change this data frame.

PS: this dataframe is has 2601 edges in it, and all states in the US.

Comment: Can you clarify what a 0 or a 1 means?

Comment: You just removed the [mcve] from your question. What are you trying to accomplish..?

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite tell what you mean by an edge or loop of 0.  I'm presuming you mean that a 0 means no edge and a 1 means an edge.

The command `graph.add_edges_from([test3])` is expecting a list of edges as its input (something like `[(1,2), (2,3), (1,5)]`).  You are giving it a list whose only entry is `test3`.

Networkx has a built in function for reading in from a pandas dataframe, `from_pandas_dataframe(df, source, target, edge_attr=None, create_using=None)`.

However, it expects that every row is an edge (if you just want to assign an attribute of 0 or 1 to the edges, then you're set).  Check [the documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).

If you mean for a 0 to be interpreted as not having an edge, then you would need to strip out those entries before calling this.  Otherwise, you can look at [the source code](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/networkx/convert_matrix.html#from_pandas_dataframe) and you can pretty much follow it except that right before the `add_edge` command, you would add a test for whether the value is 0 or 1.

I believe the following would work (where `df` is the dataframe, `source` is name of one state column, `target` is name of other state column, `value` is name of the 0/1 column:

```
g=nx.Graph() #undirected, no loops.
src_i = df.columns.get_loc(source)
tar_i = df.columns.get_loc(target)
val_i = df.columns.get_loc(value)
for row in df.values:
    if row[val_i] == 1:
        g.add_edge(row[src_i], row[tar_i])
```